# PhantomJS screen capture: unsupported browser message

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJs and sometimes when i take a screenshot of a browser I get recorded an "unsupported browser" message on the recorded screenshot...

which agent should I use? why doe it happen?

my template has this line

```
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36';
```

Comment: An afterthought to my answer: could you show *where* in your script you're setting the useragent?

Answer (score 1):

> page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36';

Chrome 37 is a pretty old browser. Using the useragent for Chrome from the recent year works fine most of the time.

Another reason for such a warning (although it is less likely) could be PhantomJS lacking some recent browser features, like ES6 *(although [v2.5 beta 2 for Windows](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.5.0-beta2-windows.zip) is rather decent in this aspect, being relatively unstable overall)*.

If you are not too invested in PhantomJS at the time I'd suggest you try [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) which is very close in syntax to it but has the newest dev Chromium underneath.

Comment: yeah i checked the every latest user agents and I replaced it in my template.  Now I don't get that message anymore!

Comment: i'll try puppeteer... i'm not super in love with phantom to be honest...

Comment: hey @Vaviloff , i tried Puppetron and it's greta, but i have no clue how to install it on my server / how to run nodejs... i mean i used to use it but now i forgot/....can you please address me to a guide or something? thanks

Answer (score -1):

You may want to randomly switch agents to prevent the scraping preventing program made by some websites.

You could also load the web driver from the local machine to prevent this.